# Is it possible to get gmail from a time interval using Gmail API?

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

For example, I want to get all emails this week, or all emails from Monday to Friday. Will that be possible? And I'm using python Gmail API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a `query` on your listing of messages and use `newer_than`:

```
ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list('me').setQ('newer_than:7d').execute();
```

You can also use `after` and `before` with time since the epoch in seconds. If you would want e.g. the messages between `Mon, 04 Sep 2017 00:00:00 GMT` and `Fri, 08 Sep 2017 23:59:59 GMT` you would write:

```
ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list('me').setQ('after:1504483200 before:1504915199').execute();
```

Comment: .setQ() doesn't work on python bindings with current versions, code that works would in python be something like:
`results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', maxResults=requested_count, pageToken=next_page, q="newer_than:7d has:attachment").execute()`, note that for python, q is a named parameter to the list() function.

Answer (score 0):

Seem list [parameters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) doesn't support filter by date time as you expected.
So I thought you can list `messages` then filter on [internalDate](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) field.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid the api documentation shows the internalDate would be in a timestamp format. Not exactly the date format I want to use.

Comment: You can convert between datetime format or timestamp to compare.

Comment: This is incorrect, send a q="filter" named parameter to the list() function where filter is your filter, eg. `"newer_than:7d"`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering). You can pass a timestamp as `query` while getting the message list. For getting the emails of Monday to Friday, you can put your logic to get the timestamp between those days and then use that timestamp.

Hope this will help you out.